# Can .NET Framework 4.0 handle concurrent requests on the same endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have this my `WebMethod`:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[SoapHeader("Header")]
public string GetStatementNotDownloadedAsync(string uniqueId, string type)
```

When I send 50 concurrent requests to this endpoint, they are processed one after another.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It no different then clicking a button, and waiting for a post back.

the JavaScript (client side) is asynchronous, but the server side has to process each request from your browser session.

You confusing threaded processing vs that of parallel processing. They are VAST different concepts. Remember, you can run a web server with one processor!!!

Some developers fall in the trap of equating multithreading to parallelism. That is not accurate. You can have multithreading on a single core machine, but you can only have parallelism on a multi core machine.

So, in most cases, the web server WILL use multiple cores (parallel processing) for different users. But, for you the ONE user, you really only have a threaded  model, and if you want to run each ajax call as parallel, then you have to write code that starts a new process thread on the server. (but then returning a value going to be rather difficult).

In fact, your browser is a threaded model. It can't really do 2 things at once! - but to be fair, browsers now can use more then one core but in general, a browser will work with one CPU, and that even includes when it is downloading say multiple images to display.

What actually occurs is each "image request" occurs sequential (each request is small - takes little time).  Now, all the requests are "done". The web server can then start to push out the multiple requests, and that can be both parallel and threaded, or even work NOT as parallel processing (each image stream gets some thread processing from the browser - it is NOT parallel multiple CPU processing when this occurs).

So, a ajax call from JavaScript is threaded. The client js code request is made and the JavaScript code keeps running past that request and then finishes its routine and ajax call. Then the callback (ajax return can occur, and the return "success" routine is then called/run client side).

So the web server "end point" can handle multiple requests - but that would be from different users - not a single user - from that single user, they are queued up, and run one after another.

The problem is not the requests!!! - The problem is doing the work and processing of each request AFTER they been  made! - those run on a threaded model, not a parallel model.